# Bijection, Surjection, defining inverse, proof

Tags: logic, solution-verification

Prove both the following:

1. If **f** : A → B is bijective, an inverse *g* of *f* exists. (You will have to define such a *g*, show it
   is a well-defined function, and show that it really is the inverse of *f*.)
2. Show that if **f** : A → B has an inverse *g*, then *f* is bijective.

(1) Definition

Let $f: A\to B$. We say that $f$ is surjective if for all b ∈ B, there exists an a ∈ A
such that f(a) = b.

We say that f is injective if whenever f(a1) = f(a2) for some a1, a2 ∈ A, then
a1 = a2.

We say that f is bijective if it is both injective and surjective.

For the first proof:

1. let $f: A\to B$ be bijective.
2. let $g: B\to A$ where y ∈ B

Since **f** is surjective, there exists an **[x]** ∈ A such that f(x) = y

3. let $g(y) = x$

Because **f** is injective, x is unique thus, **g** is well-defined.

would this be valid for the first part?

Comment: The two questions are just one if and only if statements. For $(1)$, after defining $g$, note that $f(a)=b\implies g(b)=a$ and since $f$ is injective, then $a$ is unique and thus $g$ is bijective. It remains to show that $g$ is the inverse of $f$ and is well defined.